# how to insert datetime into SQlite

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to make a test to insert a record into a SQLite badabase in Flask.
The **model.py** defined as:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer().with_variant(
        Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    release_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    scenes_movie = db.relationship('Scene', backref='movies')

    def details(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'release_date': self.release_date,
        }

    def insert(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

In **test.py**

```
my_date=date.today()
release_date = datetime(my_date.year, my_date.month, my_date.day)
print(release_date)
print(type(release_date))
self.new_movie = {
            "title": "movie1",
            "release_date":release_date
        }

def test_post_insert_movies(self):
res = self.client().post('/movies', json=self.new_movie, headers={'Authorization':'Bearer ' + self.producer_header})
data = json.loads(res.data)
self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
self.assertEqual(data['success'], True)
```

The **api.py** for the add endpoint defined:

```
@app.route("/movies", methods=['POST'])
    @requires_auth("post:movies")
    def add_movies(payload):
        body = request.get_json()
        title = body.get('title')
        release_date=body.get('release_date')
```

The **error and result** is:

```
2021-03-10 00:00:00

<class 'datetime.datetime'>

[2021-03-10 13:14:00,753] ERROR in app: Exception on /movies [POST]    

sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.  

[SQL: INSERT INTO movies (title, release_date) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: [{'release_date': 'Wed, 10 Mar 2021 00:00:00 GMT', 'title': 'movie1'}]] 

ERROR: test_post_insert_movies (__main__.CastingAgencyTestCase)                                                                                                             ----------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
File "test1.py", line 57, in test_post_insert_movies  
data = json.loads(res.data) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads  
return _default_decoder.decode(s)  
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode  
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())  
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode  
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

As you can see from print(release_date): 2021-03-10 00:00:00, it seems it becomes {'release_date': 'Wed, 10 Mar 2021 00:00:00 GMT'} when inserting into SQLite.

The problem is really coming from the DateTime format? It is from flask sqlachemy, sqlite, json or? And where should I format the DateTime or?
Thanks.

Comment: Try looking into your JSON encoder\decoder. Datetimes cannot natively be sent as JSON, so this often has to be handled manually. Put an IPDB prompt and check what exactly goes into your `request.json.get("release_date")`. If there's a string, you should convert it into a `datetime.datetime` instance. Another way is to send UNIX timestamps, since they are plain numbers and are JSON-friendly.

Comment: I@Icebreaker454, thank you. I added the JSON part to the error and result, and add the endpoint defined at api.py part in the original thread. These what you mean or? If I am right, the value is char(0) or ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried to use postgresql, then no problem. It seems there is problem with SQLite, if everything defined as above. Maybe there is another way to define for SQLite, please feel free to add the answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`release_date=body.get('release_date')` return a string.

convert the string `release_date` into python date object and it will work.

Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_str = '09/19/18 13:55:26'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```